# JavaScript switch with logical operators?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```
for (var count = 1; count < 6; count++) {
    switch (count) {
        case (2):   document.write("hi"); break;     
        case (count > 3):   document.write("bye"); break;    
        case (count >= 4): document.write("lol"); break;
    }
}
```

Because it's not working the way I expect, not printing bye and lol, it makes me think this is invalid in JavaScript. I tried looking for some examples to see if people do this on Google, and I saw none. So is this valid or not? or Why might this not work?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

When [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/switch) is interpreted, the expression in the parentheses is compared to values of the particular cases.

So in your case the value of `count` would be compared to the values of `2`, `count > 3` and `count >= 4`. And that won’t work. Although you can rewrite it and compare to `true` to get it working:

```
switch (true) {
    case (count == 2):
        document.write("hi");
        break;
    case (count > 3):
        document.write("bye");
        break;
    case (count >= 4):
        document.write("lol");
        break;
}
```

But that’s not how `switch` is supposed to be used.

Use `if` statements instead:

```
if (count == 2) {
    document.write("hi");
} else if (count > 3) {
    document.write("bye");
} else if (count >= 4) {
    document.write("lol");
}
```

---

**Edit**    Since you use the `switch` cases exclusively (break if a case matches), my `switch`-to-`if`/`else` translation is correct.

But the `count >= 4` case/branch will never be applied since `count > 3` is true (also) for `count` values greater or equal 4.

To fix this problem (write “bye” *and* “lol” for values greater or equal 4), remove the last `else` to make the last `if` statement independent from the preceding:

```
if (count == 2) {
    document.write("hi");
} else if (count > 3) {
    document.write("bye");
}
if (count >= 4) {
    document.write("lol");
}
```

Comment: @Doug: Remove the last `else` at it will.

Comment: There are still problems with order of evaluation in both the switch and if statements. See my comment below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312817/javascript-switch-with-logical-operators/3282442#3282442

Answer (score 16):

*This is a correction to [Gumbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312817/javascript-switch-with-logical-operators/2312837#2312837). I'm writing a separate answer only because this won't fit as a comment.*

**Edit:** Gumbo suggested in a comment that I may have misread Doug's intention. If the OP really wants both "bye" and "lol" to be printed out for count >= 4, then we need to remove a `break` from the `switch`. The cases are now back in the original order, so that "bye" and "lol" are printed in that order (which is apparently the OP's intent.)

```
switch (true) {
    case (count == 2):
        document.write("hi");
        break;
    case (count > 3):
        document.write("bye");
        // No break here; just fall through.
    case (count >= 4):
        document.write("lol");
        break;
}
```

In this case, I agree with Gumbo that the revised `if` statement is correct.

**Original answer follows (assumes that the OP really wanted *either* "lol" or "bye" to print, but not both.)**

The `switch` statement that [Gumbo wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312817/javascript-switch-with-logical-operators/2312837#2312837) won't work for count >= 4, for much the same reason that Gumbo's original `if` statement won't work: Because the cases are evaluated in sequence, count >= 4 implies that the second case (count > 3) will be executed; so the script will never reach the test for count >= 4. To fix this, the tests should be executed in the reverse order, from highest to lowest:

```
switch (true) {
    case (count >= 4):
        document.write("lol");
        break;
    case (count > 3):
        document.write("bye");
        break;
    case (count == 2):
        document.write("hi");
        break;
}
```

The corrected `if` statement is still not right either, because for count >= 4 it will produce **both** `bye` and `lol` on the output. Again, the tests within the `if` ladder should be arranged to go from highest to lowest values:

```
if (count >= 4) {
    document.write("lol");
} else if (count > 3) {
    document.write("bye"); 
} else if (count == 2) {
    document.write("hi");
}
```

This isn't an ideal example, because if `count` is an integer, then evaluating `count >= 4` and `count > 3` will produce the same results -- `true` for count >= 4, `false` otherwise. That wouldn't be the case if `count` is a floating-point value (but then, a floating-point value named "count" would raise other concerns.)

Comment: Doug didn’t give a precise description about what result he expected (“printing bye and lol” is not a precise description). That’s why I just wrote a working `switch` example and an equivalent `if`-`else` example to that.

Comment: You know, I missed that: We're all so hard-wired to include a break in each case clause; it didn't occur to me that the OP *wants* both cases to execute. I'm going to update my answer to cover that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You use the case clause in the wrong way. You should provide a value that will be compared to the value in the switch clause ... and not a boolean expression like this `count>2`

In this case this boolean expression will be cast to true or false (1 or 0) and compared to your value count and sometimes may work, sometimes - not.

You should consider replacing it with if statements.

Answer (score 2):

The `switch` normally needs a **fixed** condition/value; because your `count` variable changes every time, it goes against that. Use `if-else` condition instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should swap your last two cases.

Comment: @ anthares: not enough to get it to work, but it is a bug that will prevent it from working the way he is expecting.

Comment: See my answer, you cannot put boolean expressions in the case statement ... it will not be evaluated how you expect. It will be compared to the count variable.
@user210118 even swapping the last two cases will prevent from working the way OP is expecting.

Comment: @doug: > 3 will catch cases that should fall into >= 4.

Comment: @anthares: you're missing the point.  yes, we realize that the code was broken the way he had it but once he has addressed that issue (in a manner outlined by you and others), he needs to swap his last two case statements as 'lol' will never be output the way it sits now.

Comment: And even when he swap then .. it still won't work... I now this case in unreachable, but what is the point of correcting wrong code with another wrong code ... Your answer is not a solution.