# Javascript Case Error

Tags: javascript

I've got a question over here..

I got a really simple BMI calculator, its not even a calculator but the think about the idea behind it.. I just made a Case but it didn't work. (I know the value's to be healthy or obesitas are wrong, just doing it for the idea!)

Here You can see the code where I got the problem(Line 19 at the case with <=)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test BMI</title>
    <style>
        label{
        display:block;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function calc(){

            var lengte = document.getElementById("length").value;
            var gewicht = document.getElementById("gewicht").value;
            var bmi = gewicht / (lengte * lengte);
            var getal = parseInt(bmi);
            document.getElementById('uitkomst').innerHTML += "";
            switch (getal){

            case <= 17:
            document.getElementById('uitkomst').innerHTML = "U are far to light " + gewicht + "kilo!";
            break;

            case <= 23 :

            document.getElementById('uitkomst').innerHTML = "U are in good shape" + gewicht + "kilo!"; 
            break;

            default:
            document.getElementById('uitkomst').innerHTML = "just a test";




            }
            document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = bmi.toFixed(1);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="margin-left:50px;">
        <h1>BMI Berekenen</h1>
        <label>Lengte CM</label>
            <input type="text" id="length"><br/>

        <label>Gewicht KG</label>
            <input type="text" id="gewicht">
        <button id="bereken" onclick="calc()">Bereken je BMI</button>
        <div id="uitkomst">
        </div>
        <div id="advies">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help me out with this little problem I got in my code:)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312817/javascript-switch-with-logical-operators

Comment: Thanks, just Remembered it.. Thanks for remembering!

Answer (score 4):

You can not have conditions like this in `case`. You should use `if-else if-else` blocks like bellow.

```
var getal = parseInt(bmi);
document.getElementById('uitkomst').innerHTML += "";
if(getal <= 17){
    document.getElementById('uitkomst').innerHTML = "U are far to light " + gewicht + "kilo!";
}
else if(getal <= 23){
    document.getElementById('uitkomst').innerHTML = "U are in good shape" + gewicht + "kilo!"; 
}
else
    document.getElementById('uitkomst').innerHTML = "just a test";
```

Comment: Ah just remembered that cases are not for that kind of work:) Thanks for remembering me! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why *should* you use if-else statements? There are many other valid, if not better, workarounds.

Comment: @minseong Like what workarounds? If-else statements are easy to read, intuitive, and efficient for what he's doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have values on the case conditions unless you use the 'method 2' on the bottom of this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

> Method two
>
> This is the "hacky" method; on line 2, where you would usually find
>   switch(foo), we instead put an invariant true, and place conditional
>   logic (instead of constants) into the case statements:

```
var foo = 1;
switch (true) { // invariant TRUE instead of variable foo
    case foo >= 0 && foo <= 3:
        alert('yes');
        break;
    default:
        alert('not');
}
```

Comment: Link only answers are considered not useful. Links break, and a phrase like "'method 2' on the bottom of this link" will then be useless. Please include the relevant parts in your answer, and keep the link only for reference or attribution.

Answer (score 0):

In switch statements, you can't have comparative operators, like `<=`, so

```
case <= 17:
```

Simply won't work. ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch))

The problem you are now faced with is to devise an alternate method, and that problem has been answered before on the site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665997/switch-statement-for-greater-than-less-than).

My personal favourite work-around proposed on that page is this one:

```
switch (true){

  case getal <= 17:
    //....
```

called a switch-range, because it involves the least typing, unlike an `if-else if-else` monstrosity.

Comment: Least typing? You forgot you need to add `break` at each branch? Also, this is slower, according to the answer you linked.